# Conjecture about the set of Sphenic numbers

Tags: number-theory, notation, prime-numbers

> Sum of a set of sphenic numbers can't be equal to the sum of *any other* set of sphenic numbers.

By that I meant, Say S is the set of sphenic numbers. Let S$_1$ $\subset$ S.
Then there is no such S$_2$ $\subset$ S so that,

S$_1$ $\neq$ S$_2$ AND $\sum S_1$ $=$ $\sum S_2$

Question 1 : Is this statement correct?

Question 2 : Is this formulation mathematically right? I mean even if the statement is wrong, is the way that I expressed it conveys mathematical notations/rules etc. Or, how a mathematician would write it if s/he intended to convey the same message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The statement is not correct.  230+1310=231+1309.  [Sphenic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphenic_number) gives the first sequential pair (and implies there are more) and the first run of three.

2) I'm not a mathematician, but the formulation seems fine to me.  You might define Sphenic numbers so people don't have to look it up

Comment: I believe he is looking for same sums, not necessarily consecutive. For instance 2*3*5 + 11*3*5 = 13*3*5 is a smaller set than what you have.

Comment: This was just the first example I found.  Also, pick any pairs of primes with a common difference, like 7/13 and 23/29.  Then p*q*(7+29)=p*q*(13+23) for any p,q that are not 7, 13, 23, or 29.

Comment: @Ross: Yes, I was only pointing out that 'first pair' is misleading.

Comment: @Moron:  your version also gives an infinite set from any pair of twin primes.

Comment: @Ross: Yes, that is how I generated the example: using twin primes :-)

Answer (score 2):

Question 2: Instead of $\sum S_1$ you can write $$\sum_{k \in S_1} k.$$

Comment: Thanks. Is it for the reason that in the literature k[small letter] denotes elements and S[capital letter] denotes sets? Or, for other reasons?

Comment: @Sazzad: Upper or lower case is not the main point (although the convention is as you describe). Rather it's that what comes after the summation sign should describe what you are adding up, in your case _numbers_ (not sets).